# Centrar texto indiferentemente de las lineas que tenga el texto

Tags: css, html5, css3

Lo que necesito hacer es que el texto salga centrado con respecto a la imagen, es decir que si el texto tiene 2 lineas como se ve en la imagen cuadra perfectamente pero si tiene solo 1 queda raro y me gustaría que bajase hasta centrarse. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto por css dinámicamente?

He intentado dos soluciones:

Elemento HTML:

```
<div class="taskRecipient" data-id="<?php echo $value->taskId; ?>">
    <div class="miniTaskImageRecipient">
        <img class="miniTaskImage" src="<?php echo $value->image; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="miniTaskTitle"><?php echo $value->title; ?></div>
</div>
```

CSS Actual:

```
.taskRecipient{
    position: relative;
    padding: 3%;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-out;
    transition: all 0s ease-out;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.miniTaskImageRecipient {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.miniTaskImage {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

.miniTaskTitle {
    color: #252525;
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Poppins-Medium';
    padding-top: 1%;
}
```

CSS prueba1:

```
.miniTaskTitle {
    color: #252525;
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Poppins-Medium';
    padding-top: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 10%;
}
```

Esto me centra el contenedor al centro con lo que descuadra los titulos con 2 lineas.

CSS prueba2:

```
.miniTaskTitle {
    color: #252525;
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Poppins-Medium';
    padding-top: 1%;
    trasnform:translateY(50%)
}
```

Tammbién me centra el contenedor al centro descuadrando los titulos de dos lineas.

¿ Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

[image: Alineación]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo más facil es usar *flexbox*, solo tienes que añadir `display:flex` y `align-items: center`, si tienes más elementos dentro ya habría que ajustar porque con flex se pondrán todos en una misma linea por defecto:

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
<div class="contenedor">Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
```

Comment: Esta solución va genial y además es super sencilla de aplicar. Muchas gracias!!!